# R Package MicrobiomeSeq Unable to be installed: ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'microbiomeSeq'

Tags: r

I am trying to download microbiomeseq but it kept having problems with it. I have tried downloading adespatial, KMDA but still can't install microbiomeseq. Below is the error message that I've received:

```
library(devtools) # Load the devtools package
install_github("umerijaz/microbiomeSeq") # Install the package
Downloading GitHub repo umerijaz/microbiomeSeq@HEAD
Skipping 6 packages not available: AnnotationDbi, GO.db, preprocessCore, impute, phyloseq, DESeq2
── R CMD build ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpygloEn\remotes1cb4830a9673d\umerijaz-microbiomeSeq-ffa0090/DESCRIPTION' ...
─  preparing 'microbiomeSeq':
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building 'microbiomeSeq_0.1.tar.gz'
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'microbiomeSeq' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: object 'beta.div' is not exported by 'namespace:adespatial'
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'microbiomeSeq'
* removing 'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/microbiomeSeq'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpygloEn/file1cb482bc25721/microbiomeSeq_0.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

How can I move forward in solving this problem?

Tried downloading Adespatial then restart R, tried `install.packages("bit64")` then restart R.

Comment: not familiar with the package, but the error gives you pointers. Be mindful that there are additional dependencies "listed" (and not available): 'Skipping 6 packages not available: AnnotationDbi, GO.db, preprocessCore, impute, phyloseq, DESeq2' ... you may have to get them (and their dependencies in place first). good luck

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.